# Transform local template variable to global

Tags: twig

Is there a way to transform a variable from a particular template into a global one to be used in another template?
Example:

neworder.twig Template
Variable -> `{{order ['id']}}`

orderlist.twig Template
I would like to use the same `{{order ['id']}}` variable, which is assigned only to the Template neworder.twig

If I try to use it in another Template like the example:

```
<span href = "/ orders? id = {{order ['id']}}"> {{order ['id']}} </span>
```

I have no return on value.

It's possible?
Thank you!

Comment: What u mean with `only assinged to`? Just pass the variable from the controller to the other template?

Comment: I don't have access to any form of control
I am making changes to pre-defined themes that are available by api

Comment: So you have no control over the `PHP` side of the project and can only change the templates? If so you will need to ask the backend dev to provide the `order` instance to the other template as well. I mean the template `neworder` is loaded in another request than `orderlist` right?

Comment: Is there any interconnection between the two templates? Maybe you are "just" looking for twig [`include ... with ...`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/include.html)?

Comment: Also if you do have an `orderList` template, I'd suspect you have an `orders` variable that you can `{% for order in orders %}` on, then in the `for` loop you'll definitely be able to access the same  `order.id`

Comment: On another unrelated note `<span>` cannot have an href, on the other hand, `<a>` can.